# How to package/freeze a python code for unix?

Tags: python-3.x, unix

I have a simple python program which will do process an xls file and append it. The problem here is i cannot install packages eg. XLWINGS on prod server (due to compliance issues). However I  can install this package (XLWINGS) on my local system. I am thinking of writing a python program locally and create an UNIX executable file of it. My intention is that i will take this executable file/package to the UNIX server and run it without having to install the XLWINGS. Is this possible? If yes could you please help me with an example, I am new to Python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use virtual environment instead. Note that some packages may require native code, architecture on target system might be different, etc.

Comment: Sorry, but could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: With virtualenv (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) you can install packages such way they don't interfere with system wide installation. This way you can isolate your things and install them for yourself only.